# discrete random variable with uniformly distributed random variable

Tags: functions, inverse, random

I hope you can help me because I have no clue where to start:

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with $ p_k=P_X[X=x_k]=p(x_k) $for all $1\le k\le N$ for $N\in \Bbb N$ and distribuition function: $$F_X:\Bbb R\rightarrow [0,1], F_x(x)=\sum_{k=1}^N p_k1_{\{x_k\le x\}}.$$
$1_A$, for $A\in \mathfrak F$, is the characteristic function also written as $\mathcal X_A$.

Now there's a **uniformly distributed** random variable $U$ on $[0,1]$.
My task is to get the inverse:$F^{-1}_X(u):=\inf\{x\in \Bbb R|F_X(x)\ge u\}, u\in (0,1)$ of $F_X$. I also have to scrabble a map.

Edit:
It is$$F_x=\begin{cases}
  0,  & \text{if }x<1\\
  \sum_{k=1}^N p_k1_{\{x_k\le x\}}, & \text{if }x\le x_N\\
  1,  & \text{if }x\ge x_N 
\end{cases}$$.

Comment: Presumably what you want to do is write down what $F_X^{-1}$ is and then describe the distribution of $F_X^{-1}(U)$. Can you do the first thing?

Comment: Yes but what exactly is the explicit form of $F^{-1}_X(u)$? Does it return the sets $\{x_k\le x\}$ for $x\in \Bbb R$ or $p_k$ the Height of the Steps of $F_x$ since that distribution function is a step function

Comment: You have a formula for $F_X^{-1}$ which is quite explicit.

Comment: I'm confused, maybe I can't even see a tree while standing in the forest, just by now. :(

Comment: For example, let us say that you have a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $1/2$. Now let $y$ be a real number and let us try to compute $F_X^{-1}(y)$. Suppose $y \leq 0$. Then $F_X(x) \geq y$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ so $F_X^{-1}(y)=-\infty$. Suppose $0 \leq y<1/2$. Then $F_X(x) \geq y$ once $x \geq 0$, since $P(X=0)=1/2$. So $F_X^{-1}(y)=0$. Finally suppose $y \geq 1/2$. Then $F_X(x) \geq y$ once $x \geq 1$, so $F_X^{-1}(y)=1$. So $F_X^{-1}$ is a step function which has jumps of size ____ at the points ____.

Comment: Ok and what happens with the other $x_k$? You gave an example for a set with only one element $\{0,x_2,...,x_N\}\text{for }\Bbb N$. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If we have a set like $\{0, 1\}$.Then it would be $P(X=0)=1/2\text{ and } P(X=1)=1/2$ $\rightarrow F^{-1}_X(y)=1/2$ $ \text{once } 0\le x\le 1?$

Comment: Er, in the Bernoulli(1/2) case yes. But basically the same thing happens for a larger finite set: the position of each jump in $F_X$ is one of the finitely many values that $F_X^{-1}$ takes.

Comment: So it's $p_k=P(X=x_k)$ for $x_k\in \{x_1,...,x_N\}$ which is returned by $F^{-1}_X(u)$? Also the inverse takes $u\in(0,1)$ and what does U the uniformly distributed random value do for the inverse?

Comment: I still don't think you're really following what $F_X^{-1}$ does to a number, before we get into things about random variables. $F_X^{-1}(z)$ is the infimum of all the $x$ such that $F_X(x) \geq z$. This is $+\infty$ for $z>1$ (since $F_X \leq 1$, so you get $\inf \emptyset = +\infty$). It is $-\infty$ for $x \leq 0$ (since $F_X \geq 0$, so you get $\inf \mathbb{R} = -\infty$).  Otherwise, you are basically drawing the line $y=z$ and looking for the leftmost intersection of it with the graph of $F_X$.

Comment: For a discrete variable $X$, this will occur at one of the jumps in $F_X$ (i.e. one of the elements of the domain of the probability mass function). Thus for discrete $X$, $F_X^{-1}$ is piecewise constant, the constants being $x_k$. The *width* of the interval where $F_X^{-1}=x_k$ is the *height* of the corresponding jump, which is $p_k$. This last point is how you can understand the distribution of $F_X^{-1}(U)$ (because you should know that the probability for $U$ to lie in some interval is just the length of that interval).

Comment: The argument of $F^{-1}$ is $u\in(0,1)$. But $\lim_{u\to -\infty}F^{-1}(u)=0$ right? But there's no upper limit.

Comment: It depends what domain you choose for $F_X^{-1}$. It can be defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, but if you do so then it will only be finite on $(0,1]$. (It could be infinite at $1$ too, for example this is true for the normal distribution. But it will always be finite in $(0,1)$.)

Comment: So $ F_x=\begin{cases}
  0,  & \text{if }u<p_1\\
  x_k, & \text{if }p_1\le u\le p_N\\
  1,  & \text{if }u\ge p_N 
\end{cases}$ ? I need to give it explicitively tommorow. I'm kinda new to distributions on random variables. The second step of this task is to show that $Y:=F^{-1}_X\circ U$is a discrete random value on the same measure space with pdf in $\{x_1,...,x_N\}.$

Comment: You're still being sloppy. $F_X^{-1}(u)=\begin{cases} -\infty & u \leq 0 \\ x_1 & 0 <u<p_1 \\ x_2 & p_1 \leq u<p_1+p_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_N & \dots \\ +\infty & u>1 \end{cases}$ (leaving some things for you to fill in).

Comment: And that $ P_Y=P_X$.

Comment: $P_Y=P_X$ is easy to see if you really understand what $F_X^{-1}$ looks like, in particular that it takes on the value $x_k$ on an interval of length $p_k$.

Comment: Thank you very much know I understood. So for $Y:=F^{-1}_X\circ U$ with uniformly distributed U, $F_Y$ must'nt have the same pdf or?

Comment: $Y=F_X^{-1} \circ U$ has the same distribution as $X$, yes. This is a general fact, and is how most numerical sampling techniques work (because if I can compute $F_X^{-1}$, then I can sample from the distribution of $X$ by sampling from a uniform distribution, which reduces *many* situations down to a single problem).

Comment: If you are interested in this direction, some familiar situations where we *don't* use this technique are in sampling from the normal distribution (the inverse normal CDF is expensive to compute) and discrete variables (the basically-naive method for this case is binary search, and there are faster algorithms out there).

Comment: Therefor I only have to show that $Y$ is measurable function with finite arguments $p_k$ generated by $F_X$? Then it's discrete random variable?

Comment: Finite...arguments? What? No, you get measurability for free (because $F_X^{-1}$ is Borel), and $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$ because $P(U \in I)=|I|$ for any interval $I \subseteq (0,1)$.

Comment: Basicly I get it for free because $U$ is measureable per definition of random variable and $F^{-1}_X$ is as a step function also measurable. I need to explain it detailed because it's my homework =).

Comment: Strictly speaking you need that $F_X^{-1}$ is *Borel* measurable in order to compose it like this.

Comment: Thanks for the great help, whish I could give you some reputation. You earned it!